# Change text of element that contains other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have markup like this:

```
<li data-id="1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" style="margin: .25em; padding: .25em;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    random text
    <input type="hidden" name="global_filter[default_fields][][apple]" value="random text_again">
  </button>
</li>
```

I want to change the text "random text" to "something else".

I am able to find the text node:

```
  $li.find('button').first().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  }).text();
```

But how can I change the text? When I pass an argument to text like `text('something else')`, nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably put the text in its own container like

`<div id='changeableText'>Random Text</div>`

and then just access it directly with

`$('#changeableText').text('New text!');`

to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

You can select Just the `text()` of the button and change it.

**Note:** This will not work if more that one non marked up texts exists. E.g.

```
<li data-id="1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" style="margin: .25em; padding: .25em;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    random text
    <input type="hidden" name="global_filter[default_fields][][apple]" value="random text_again">
    another random text
  </button>
</li>
```

Otherwise her is a
**working demo:**

```js
var getNonMarkedUpText = $('button').text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "");
$('button').html($('button').html().replace(getNonMarkedUpText, 'something else'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-id="1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" style="margin: .25em; padding: .25em;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    random text
    <input type="hidden" name="global_filter[default_fields][][apple]" value="random text_again">
  </button>
</li>
```

Comment: This has the negative effect of removing the other nested elements in the button

Comment: Wait... I will find another way and update the answer in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li data-id="1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" style="margin: .25em; padding: .25em;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span id="txt1">random text</span>
    <input type="hidden" name="global_filter[default_fields][][apple]" value="random text_again">
  </button>
</li>
```

That way, you can go:

```
document.getElementById("txt1").innerText = "txet modnar";
```

Or

```
$("#txt1").text("tandom rext");
```